# Circular Quick Contact Badge

Tags: android

Hi guys I a have contact list view with Quick contact badge.It displaying square images but my requirement is to show circular quick contact badge (like below screen shot). Plz let me know how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are two methods for creating circular images. you just have to pass bitmap image to make it circular.

```
/**
 * To make image in a round shape. Use this method if you want to specify required height and width
 * 
 * @param i
 */
public static Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage, int i) {
    int targetWidth = i;
    int targetHeight = i;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
            Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
            sourceBitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
            targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}

/**
 * To make image in a round shape
 */

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    // Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
    // return _bmp;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this one. But is there any default view style in v7 library??

Comment: No there is no any default style set in any of the appcompat V7 library

Comment: You have to make it customize as I have shown you in above method

Answer (score 1):

Now a days, you should look into RoundedBitmapDrawable. A round drawable can easily be created by

```
Bitmap bitmap = <the bitmap you want to be circular>
RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Don't forget (Thanks Gil SH for pointing this out):

```
drawable.setCornerRadius(Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html

Comment: I'd love this to be a one line solution, but it's not rounding my thumbnail.  It's converting it to a drawable, but it's not round.  Any ideas?

Comment: drawable.setCornerRadius(Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0f);